# Query Regarding Google API's Login Events Availability

Tags: oauth2-playground

I'm currently in the process of integrating Google API into my tenant and have been experimenting with the OAuth 2.0 Playground to gain a better understanding of its functionality.

Specifically, I've authorized the following resources within the playground:

1. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly
2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly

Following authorization, I proceeded to log in to a Gmail inbox belonging to a user (for instance, 'user2@glab12.avanan.net') using the standard Google Login page. Subsequently, I accessed the user's settings and initiated a password change.

As per the documentation, I then sent a GET request to the following URL:

`https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/login?maxResults=25`

To my surprise, while I observed the password change event after a few minutes, I did not receive any "login_success" or "login_failure" events. Despite repeated attempts over the past two days, these events have not been forthcoming.

I would greatly appreciate your guidance on why these login events may not be available through this endpoint and under what circumstances they are typically accessible.

Thank you for your attention to this matter.